# C# method generics with class implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

**UPDATE**: This does not work the way I was hoping it would so, as others have stated below, this is not really a valid approach. Will be handling what I need another way.

I've created an interface with a method using a generic parameter, and a class that implements it. But in the class implementation, I get an error that the class doesn't implement a member that is on the class. Which seems odd.

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    String MethodA<T>(T obj);
}

public class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    public String name { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        this.name = "My Name";
    }

    public String MethodA<ClassA>(ClassA aClass)
    {
        String result = aClass.name;    //ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
        return result;
    }   
}

public class ClassB : InterfaceA
{
    public String test1 { get; set; }

    public ClassB()
    {
        this.test1 = String.Empty;
    }

    public String MethodA<ClassB>(ClassB obj)
    {
        String result = obj.test1;
        return result;
    }
}

public class ClassC : InterfaceA
{
    public String test2 { get; set; }

    public ClassC()
    {
        this.test2 = String.Empty;
    }

    public String MethodA<ClassC>(ClassC obj)
    {
        String result = obj.test2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

This gives "*Error CS1061   'ClassA' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'ClassA' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

I'm sure I've got something wrong here but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Why is `MethodA` even generic in the first place? If you only want it to take a `ClassA`, then just do that.

Comment: Because this is a simplified example, and in the real one I've got a dozen or more classes implementing that interface, and their parameters for that method will need to take different types.

Comment: @stuartd why does the compiler infer that `aClass` is of type `InterfaceA`? Why does stating `MethodA<ClassA>` not instruct the compiler to see `aClass` as `ClassA` but as `InterfaceA`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely caused by you re-using the `ClassA` name for the generic type. In this case, that is hiding the real definition of `ClassA`. So, use another name for it, it's common to use `T` in C#. Now it could be any type, but if you want to make sure it has the `name` property, then you need a generic type constraint. For example, this would work:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    string MethodA<T>(T obj) where T : ClassA;
                           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

public class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    public String name { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        this.name = "My Name";
    }

    public string MethodA<T>(T aClass) where T : ClassA
                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    {
        String result = aClass.name;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Of course, there's now a weird relationship between `ClassA` and `InterfaceA` so you may want to extract the `name` property out as it's own interface too. For example:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string name { get; }
}
```

Now your other code would look like this:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    string MethodA<T>(T obj) where T : INamed;
                           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

public class ClassA : InterfaceA, INamed
{
    public String name { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        this.name = "My Name";
    }

    public string MethodA<T>(T aClass) where T : INamed
                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    {
        String result = aClass.name;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need the interface to be generic and not specific to Class A. So I can also have:   

    public class ClassB : InterfaceA
    public String MethodA<ClassB>(ClassB obj)

Comment: Then as I said in my last sentence, extract the `name` property into it's own interface and use that as the constraint.

Comment: For every property in each class that uses that interface? The properties of the classes differ and that method on each uses that classes properties.

Comment: It almost seems like your intent is to specialize the generic...ala c++. But that's not how generics work in c#

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the fact that you know that `ClassA` has a `name` property.

The compiler sees that `MethodA` is a member of `InterfaceA` (an interface that ClassA implements).  That method is generic in type `T`, where `T` has no constraints.  You are implementing `MethodA` with `ClassA` as the type parameter.  You could have used any type.  When you call the `aClass.name` getter, the compiler says "Hey, there are no contraints on T, you don't get to use any of its members".

To fix this, add an interface like:

```
public interface IHaveAName 
{
    string name {get;}
}
```

and then change your interface definition to:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    String MethodA<T>(T obj) where T: IHaveAName;
}
```

Then declare that ClassA implements both interfaces:

```
public class ClassA : InterfaceA, IHaveAName
```

You may want to rethink what you are doing (my guess is that the reason you are doing this would be more apparently if this wasn't a dummied up example with meaningless names).  It's hard to fathom why you have things structured this way given the information you have presented.

Comment: I haven't included the "why" because that's not my question and I don't want to write a novel explaining what I'm doing. I can do what I need to another way, it's just that if this worked this would be simpler. Which is why my question is can this work? If the answer is no, fine. So since it doesn't seem to work this way then I'll just use my other approach.

Comment: @SoftwareNinja: I understand.  I appreciate the nice tiny [mcve] - if only everyone was able to condense a problem so well.  I just wanted to point out that there isn't much else we can say given the information you presented.  Both answers are similar and provide a path to a solution; though probably not the one you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If in a given class you always want to call the method with the same parameter type, the
solution is to add the generic type parameter to the interface instead:

```cs
interface InterfaceA<T>
{
    String MethodA(T obj);
}
```

Then you can implement it like this

```cs
public class ClassA : InterfaceA<ClassA>
{
    public String name { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        this.name = "My Name";
    }

    public String MethodA(ClassA aClass)
    {
        String result = aClass.name;    //No more error here.
        return result;
    }   
}
```